# view controller displays only once

Tags: ios, xcode5, viewcontroller

I am using a tab bar controller with nine tabs. The 9th tab "Info" then pushes to another View Controller "Feedback" (that holds a link to our feedback form)

All works fine on testing, with this exception:

After opening the app, then the "More" tab, you can navigate to Info / Feedback and back out, but once you have gone to the Feedback tab, you can no longer choose Info successfully.

This only fails when you go all the way to Feedback the first time; not when you only go to Info and back out.

Here's a [screenshot](http://www.safre.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/atl-fire-2-18a.png) of MainStoryboard:

[image]

Comment: You will probably need to put some of your code up.

Comment: How do you show the ViewControllers? Why do you have multiple Navigation Controllers?

Comment: That Navigation Controller between "Info onF Dmaps View Controller" and "Feedback - Feedback" seems unnecessary, doesn't it? Can't you just push the Feedback?

Comment: Eliminating the Navigation Controller between Info and Feedback fixed the issue. Many thanks.